# How to switch Tab bar on Previous and Next Button click event using React native tab view plugin

Tags: react-native

In react-native-tab-view, I want to add 2 buttons at bottom (Previous and Next) On clicking on Previous/Next button the Tab bar get change. Please help me, how I can achieve this. I tried by getting index value of tab but is doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using react-native-tab-view plugin for tab. In tab view their is a Tab bar which is scrollable and by clicking on tab they can switch. But I want to add 2 buttons in the tab Previous and Next Button. By clicking on Previous button the tab should switch on previous tab. And on clicking on Next button tab should move forward.